# How to adjust this jQuery code to target div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a reusable modal code that I use to easily load multiple modals.  The problem I ran into was I had the div I use to display my errors set using an id.  when I tried displaying errors in the second modal, obviously it didn't work because you can't have more than one element with the same id.

I would like to adjust my jQuery code in that erases any errors when the modal window opens.

Here is my code for the modals.

```
function loadModal($modalNum, $modalTitle, $modalFile) {

echo '<!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="'.$modalNum.'" class="modal">  

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modalContent">
        <div class="modalHeader">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>'.$modalTitle.'</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="modalBody">
            <!-- Error section -->
            <div class="errors"></div>

            <!-- include form to show -->';
            include($modalFile);


    echo '      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';

}
```

The piece of above code that I'm targeting.

```
<!-- Error section -->
<div class="errors"></div>
```

Here is my script that loads the window.

```
    $('.openModal').on('click', function(){


    $('#'+$(this).data('modal')).css('display','block');
    $("#form")[0].reset();
    while ($('.errors').firstChild) {
    $('.errors').removeChild($('.errors').firstChild);
            }
    })
```

Here is the portion of code that I cannot figure out.

```
while ($('.errors').firstChild) {
  $('.errors').removeChild($('.errors').firstChild);
}
```

Prior to changing it to try and read a class it looked like this. This was also when my html for the modal had the div as an id  `<div id='errors'></div>`.

```
while (errors.firstChild) {
  errors.removeChild(errors.firstChild);
}
```

How can I change this section of code to target my error div using the class
?

Comment: I will try when I get back to my computer.  Had to take a break, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either [scope](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) your search or [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the element inside the modal, both will return the same element. Also, the [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method is more convenient. And you can use the same approach for your other elements too, like the `form` you are targeting:

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function(){
    targetModal = $('#'+$(this).data('modal'));
    $("#form")[0].reset();
    // Both are equivalent
    errors = $(".errors", targetModal);
    errors = targetModal.find(".errors");
    errors.empty();

    targetModal.css('display','block');
});
```